# Why is Microsoft OpenID not available to login with?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

With Hotmail, Live, and Outlook, being extremely popular, and Microsoft accounts numbering in the hundreds of millions, why is Microsoft OpenID not available to login with?

Comment: If it's OpenID, it's *available*, it's just not *pre-listed in convenient one-click form*.

Comment: "[How to use Microsoft Account in an openID site?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/989319/how-to-use-microsoft-account-in-an-openid-site)" on Stack Overflow may be relevant, though the answers are *very* out of date.

Comment: So it seems Microsoft accounts no longer have OpenID 2.0 protocol support, meaning that stackexchange.com would have to offer OAuth login, just like it's done for Facebook and Google.  I'll leave this as a feature request and hope the webmasters consider it.